# how to return from doInBackground only after the the thread inside it is finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I started a Volley JsonObject Request from asynctak and i want to return from doinBackground after the volley request is completed. I know it return from the doInBackground after it successfully started the thread. But how do i return after the Volley Thread is finished!

In this code I am getting a null value of Weather object. All the functions are working correctly.

Code:

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    String url=getURL();
    final JSONObject[] mJsonWeather = {null};
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            mJsonWeather[0]=response;

      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("Error","can't process json result");
        }
    });
    MySingleton.getInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQue(jsonObjectRequest);

    return mJsonWeather[0];

}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObjectWeather) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObjectWeather);

        Weather weather = getJsonWeatherData(jsonObjectWeather);
        setWeatherobj(weather);

}
```

Comment: You do realize that the primary purpose of Volley was to remove the need for an AsyncTask that does HTTP requests, right? In other words, remove the AsyncTask completely from the equation

Comment: In case of Volley request `Asynctask` should not be in picture , Also why you are calling a Volley thread from Asynctask thread .

Comment: yes but suppose we are doing volley operations in a method then before completing the request it is returning the result with a null!

Comment: You handle the volley result from onResponse. anything outside of that is ran synchronously, in-order. Async code is hard, but callbacks are important to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood something about the *async* part of `AsyncTask`. It means it runs **asynchronously**

Sure your code will run, but while Volley is running in a separate thread, you've gone ahead to `return mJsonWeather[0];`, which is null.

No AsyncTask needed. Call this section of code directly in the Activity

**EDIT** "Clean code"

```
// Can define this wherever
Response.Listener<JSONObject> dataListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Weather weather = getJsonWeatherData(response);
        setWeatherobj(weather);
  }
};

// This error listener is almost always the same, anyway, right?
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("Error","can't process json result");
    }
}

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
    null, // Data
    dataListener, // onSuccess
    errorListener // onError
);

MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
    .addToRequestQue(jsonObjectRequest); // Some RequestQueue
```

Comment: that worked i just checked, but i want to have my mainactivity clean. I was trying to have some abstraction by writing that code in other class. Is there any way to do that in other class?

Comment: Yes, there is, but you should accept this answer since it worked for you, and instead post a new question with your new problem

Comment: yes, but it answered the question indirectly, please suggest an answer.

Comment: Hint: extract out the `Response.Listener<JSONObject>` from the Volley call. Move that to a parameter of a method in another class. Use that parameter value when you make the Volley request object.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask return results of operation in .onPostExecute() method. You should get result from there ( it is executed on main thread)

Comment: onPostExecute() method is exceuted just after starting the thread, iwant thisto start after completing the volley thread inside doInBackground().

Comment: Actually, no, .opPostExecute() run when you .doInBackground() is complete . Maybe the issue is, that you call asynchronous method from Volley instead of synchronous method and because of that it return immediately.

Comment: Consider not using AsyncTask, it is obsolete technic, use rxJava library instead

Answer (score 0):

Volley already implements a separate thread for do the request. You can define a onPostExecute (a callback) and do it when the volley request is finished. For insance:

```
public void doRequest() {
    String url=getURL();
    final JSONObject[] mJsonWeather = {null};
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            mJsonWeather[0]=response;
            Weather weather = getJsonWeatherData(jsonObjectWeather);
        setWeatherobj(weather);

      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("Error","can't process json result");
        }
    });
    MySingleton.getInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQue(jsonObjectRequest);

    return mJsonWeather[0];

}
```